# model not showing up in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-settings, django-apps

I have ceated several django apps and stuffs for my own fun and so far everything has been working fine.

Now I just created new project (django 1.2.1) and have run into trouble from 1st moments.

I created new app - game and new model Game. I created admin.py and put related stuff into it. Ran syncdb and went to check into admin. Model did not show up there.

I proceeded to check and doublecheck and read through previous similar threads:
[Registered models do not show up in admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839927/registered-models-do-not-show-up-in-admin)
[Django App Not Showing up in Admin Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694259/django-app-not-showing-up-in-admin-interface)

But as far as I can tell, they don't help me either. Perhaps someone else can point this out for me.

models.py in game app:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models

class Game(models.Model):
      type = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=1)
      teamone = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
      teamtwo = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
      gametime = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False)
```

admin.py in game app:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from jalka.game.models import Game
from django.contrib import admin

class GameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      list_display    = ['type', 'teamone', 'teamtwo', 'gametime']
      
admin.site.register(Game, GameAdmin)
```

project settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'jalka.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
      "/home/projects/jalka/templates/"
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'game',
)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
      # Example:
      # (r'^jalka/', include('jalka.foo.urls')),
      (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Hmmmm...Try change include of your app in settings.py:

**From:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'game',
    ....
```

**To:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'YOUR_PROJECT.game',# OR 'YOUR_PROJECT.Game'
```

Comment: That is one thing to try indeed. But if that truly were the case, then i doubt the model would show up in database anyway. But i will try it. just in case.

Comment: It seems that this was it. Has django really gone more strict concerning some stuff? Like i found out that 'pass' in context processors was generating errors and i had to replace pass with return {} to get rid of the errors (more here - http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/144fa6b67db420f/ec98c74e0606cbe3)

Comment: Another possibility here is that you were signed into the admin interface as a user who didn't have permission to change that model; in that case the model won't show even if everything else is correct. As such in these cases when attempting to debug it is best to ensure that you are logged in as the admin user, to rule a permissions issue out.

Comment: Where can you find the value of `YOUR_PROJECT` and where can you find the value of `game`? I know the first question might be obvious for most, but the naming is messed up on the project I'm working on

Answer (score 210):

The problem reported can be because you skipped registering the models for the admin site. This can be done, creating an `admin.py` file under your app, and there registering the models with:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel

admin.site.register(MyModel)
```

Comment: How is this answer the highest rated one? My code shows that i did have admin.site.register... and the selected answer is correct one.. so wtf...

Comment: Because people type "model not showing up in admin" into Google, try all the solutions on the first SO page they find, and upvote whatever works :-D

Comment: Still ranked ... XD
@andyhasit nice catch!

Comment: Well, this is a reasonable answer for the overall question. It is not an answer for your configuration. 

If it was asked for a different configuration, it would be redirected to this one as Dupe none-the-less. 

Therefore it is right to upvote this answer. It is the most likely cause.

Comment: after this fix do I have to run migrations again?

Comment: @dios231 Nope, it should work immediately assuming the migrations have already been applied.

Comment: Try this to automatically register all your models in admin.py: https://hackernoon.com/automatically-register-all-models-in-django-admin-django-tips-481382cf75e5

Comment: @Blcknx I agree. Forgetting to install the app is less probably compared to the chance of forgetting to register the model inside that app. I would upvote both this and the other answer, since combined they are the perfect solution. LOL

Answer (score 36):

Had the same issue with Django 2.0.

The following code didn't work:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from users import models

admin.register(models.User, UserAdmin)
```

It turns out the line

```
admin.register(models.User, UserAdmin)
```

should have been

```
admin.site.register(models.User, UserAdmin)
```

Since I didn't get any warnings, just wanted to point out this thing here too.

Comment: This is what worked for me. It is a pretty silly thing to have trip one up - it should be documented somewhere - or a warning/error emitted!

Comment: i think the same.. django dont's show any warning about this error. 2 hours looking for a solutions..  thanks guys

Comment: HOLY SMOKES! Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

I know this has already been answered and accepted, but I felt like sharing what my solution to this problem was, maybe it will help someone else.

My `INSTALLED_APPS` looked like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core',  # <---- this is my custom app
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'south',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

See, I put my app before Django's admin app, and apparently it loads them in that order. I simply moved my app right below the admin, and it started showing up :)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. Done everything right. But I didn't have permission to view the model.

Just give the required permission (view/add/edit/etc) and then check again.

Give Permission using admin panel:

1. Login to the site using the credentials for your superuser account.
2. The top level of the Admin site displays all of your models, sorted by "Django application". From the Authentication and Authorization section, you can click the Users or Groups links to see their existing records.
3. Select and add the required permission

Select and add the required permission
[image]

refer [this](https://djangobook.com/mdj2-django-admin/) to add/change permission through the admin panel

Alternative:
Using code
refer [Official Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization)

Answer (score 6):

For Django 1.10 helped to me to register the Model following way **with (admin.ModelAdmin) at the end**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import YourModel
admin.register(YourModel)(admin.ModelAdmin)
```

Comment: This worked for me and helped me find a mistake, but you probably want instead `admin.site.register(YourModel)` which is the correct way.

Answer (score 5):

It's probably very rare but I had an issue today where the permissions on the admin.py file I had created were corrupt and thus made it unreadable by django. I deleted the file and recreated it with success.

Hope that saves someone, should they stumble here with my problem.

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with registering my models (tried all the suggestions above) too until I did a very simple thing. I moved my admin.py out of the directory up to the project directory - refreshed the admin screen and moved it back and voila into the models app directory - they all appeared instantly. I'm using **PyCharm** so not sure if that was causing some problems.

My setup is exactly what the Django manual says -

**models.py**

```
class xxx(models.Model):
    ....
    def __str__(self):  # __str__ for Python 3, __unicode__ for Python 2
        return self.name
```

**admin.py**

```
from .models import xxx
admin.site.register(xxx)
```

Comment: This helped me. Pycharm was just acting weird and I had to restart the entire IDE to solve the problem. turning off/on the server didn't work for me. Wtf JetBrains...

Answer (score 4):

I am using digital ocean and also ran into this issue. The solution was a service restart. I used

service gunicorn restart

and that got the model to show up

Answer (score 3):

I just had to restart apache service. service apache2 restart. Then new models shown up.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Few of my models were not showing in the django admin dashbaord because I had not registered those models in my admin.py file.

```
//Import all the models if you have many

from store.models import *

admin.site.register(Order)
admin.site.register(OrderItem)
```

This fixed it for me. Just register and refresh your webpage and the models will be visible in the admin dashboard

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I solve this to add register of admin to `admin.py`.
And I don't need to add extra class.

Like:

```
from jalka.game.models import Game
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Game)
```

Enviroment: Win10、Django 1.8

[django](/questions/tagged/django)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and i resolved it as follow
first go to your app.py file and copy the class name.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class **ResumeConfig**(AppConfig):
name = 'resume'
```

now go to setting.py and place it in application definition as follow:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
**'resume.apps.ResumeConfig'**
]
```

save and run the commands in the terminal

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

run your server and go to /admin
your problem will be solved

Answer (score 2):

you just need to register your model.
got to admin.py file of the same app and write,

```
from .models import "Modelname"

admin.site.register(("Modelname")) 
#create tuple to register more than one model
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also like to add, that I did everything these answers said, except I did not enter on the command line `sudo service apache2 restart` which I needed to make the changes take effect. (Because I was testing on a live server on port 80 on amazon web services. I was also using an Ubuntu operating system.) That solved it for me. I hope this might help somebody.

Comment: I totally freakin' knew that I had to do this, but I had been developing on my local laptop (Ubuntu, using django server), where the restart is automatic, for so long that I forgot this.  Until I saw your answer.  Bless you!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue, 
After restart my development server model is showing in admin page.

Answer (score 1):

Change your admin code to this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Game

class GameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display    = ['type', 'teamone', 'teamtwo', 'gametime']

admin.site.register(Game, GameAdmin)
```

Also make sure the app is included in *settings.py* file and make sure you're importing the right name for your model. Another reason that can bring about this issue is putting a comma *(,)* at the end of your model fields as though it a python list.

Answer (score 1):

My new model not showing up on Admin page due to me using ADMIN_REORDER(https://pypi.org/project/django-modeladmin-reorder/) in settings.py to control model order, added a while back and forgotten. Added the new model to settings.py and it shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Saff said, your `settings.py` should be like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'YOUR_PROJECT',
    # And
    'YOUR_PROJECT.Foo',
    'YOUR_PROJECT.Bar',
)
```

Comment: Why `Foo` and why `Bar`? What does that represent?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake might be at `views.py`in your "def" you should check if you got

```
If mymodel.is_valid():
mymodel = model.save()
```

I will give you a piee of my code so you would understand it

```
@login_required(login_url='/home/')
def ask_question(request):
user_asking = UserAsking()

if request.method == "POST":
    user_asking = UserAsking(request.POST)

    if user_asking.is_valid():
        user_asking.save()

    return redirect(home)

return render(request, 'app/ask_question.html', {
    'user_asking': user_asking,
})
```

`UserAsking is a form.
i hope i did help you

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reasons is that you do not close old python processes.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on an instance of django mounted in a docker container. The code was correct but changes to admin.py were not appearing in django admin.

After quitting the django process and remounting the container with `docker-compose up`, the added models became available in django admin.

Answer (score 0):

I had all my Admin classes in a folder `./sites/` which only worked because of cercular dependencies I had. I fixed them, and everything else stopped working.

When I renamed that directory from `./sites/` to `./admin/` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to point out is that you should make sure you're signed in with a superuser.

It could be that you are signed in with a user who has limited permission on view capacity so try that.

I in Django 2.0 I still register my app using just the name of the app i.e 'game'. But the issue was in the logged in user permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I was updating a remote server with code from local, but the remote server was still using the old models in the admin screen.  Everything looked exactly the same between my local and the remote server - the database tables matched and the code was also identical.

The problem turned out the remote server was running using the venv environment.  After running `source venv/bin/activate` and then doing the migrations, the admin showed all the new models.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple models to register then use.

`admin.site.register((Model1  , Model2 , Model3))`

or

`admin.site.register([Model1  , Model2 , Model3])`

in your admin.py file.

Comment: This is a generic answer not relevant to the case.  It is also inaccurate because you propose two different ways, and one of them will most likely fail.

Comment: These both will work correctly. actually if you want to register multiple models then you need to add them into a iterable. so you can use a tuple or list.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error but I have not mentioned my app in **INSALLED_APPS**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'myapp.apps.myappConfig',
)
```

I have already registered the model but forgot to mention my app in INSTALLED_APPS and **after mentioning it works for me**

Answer (score 0):

For me, migration was an issue. If you created this new app, try doing the following:

```
python manage.py makemigrations <name_of_your_app>
python manage.py migrate <name_of_your_app>
```

You do not need to include all `admin.site.register` in a single app, you could specify them in their corresponding app at the `admin.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, `django=4.0` with `docker-compose` i was not using `ModelAdmin`, turns out registering multiple Models in one call to `admin.site.register` errors out when running migration.

So doing

```
admin.site.register(ModelA, ModelB)
```

did not work. instead, you I did something like

```
admin.site.register(ModelA)
admin.site.register(ModelB)
```

I hope it helps anyone dockerizing their Django App

Answer (score 0):

Give your user **"Superuser status"** through the edit user functionality in the admin panel.

[image]

Most probably the user you are signed in **is not a superuser** and **doesn't have the required permissions** for the newly created models.

In Django, after new models are created and migrated, the permissions of the existing users are not updated. Only the users with Superuser status can by default view, add, change and delete records for these models.

To fix the problem and avoid it in the future give "Superuser status" to your development user.

Answer (score -1):

You Make sure You have Added your Model to
admin.py file .

Example : if your model is Contact.

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Contact
admin.site.register((Contact))
```

Now your issue might be resolved if not try restarting your server.

Answer (score -2):

You only have to import(include) this:

```
from models import *
```