# Django Custom Permissions

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I added the following to my model:

```
class Meta:
        db_table = 'history'
        permissions = (
            ("View", u"View history log"),
        )
```

And I ran syncdb but my content type wasn't added nor was there an entry made to the auth_permission table. I'm looking for a way to add this permission so I can give it to certain users.

Btw, I didn't have a admin.py file. I tried adding one to my application and I tried registering my History model but when I run syncdb still nothing.

Note:This is a legacy database.

Comment: Make sure that the app containing the model is included in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: You might want to have a look at this discussion: http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/211

Comment: @Alasdair yes it does. I only have one app and it's included.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco i installed south and added it to INSTALLED_APPS and i ran syncdb but my model is still not even showing up in the admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I forgot to add my own app to the list of `INSTALLED_APPS`. Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2988540/1086938). Hope this helps someone!