# admin.site.register doesn't add my app in admin Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-settings

I'm trying to see the models in the admin. I've tried everything but nothing seems to work, could you help me?

Note: I've also tried with admin.autodiscover() but it didn't work. Also, I have installed the apps correctly and made the migrations without problems.

Here's what I have in main urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView , logout_then_login

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('homebanking/', include('Clientes.urls')),
]
```

This is in apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ClientesConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'Clientes'
```

This is what I have in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Clientes.apps.ClientesConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

In the models.py from my app, I have:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(TipoCliente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer_name = models.TextField()
    customer_surname = models.TextField()
    customer_dni = models.TextField(db_column='customer_DNI', unique=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    dob = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    branch_id = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'client'
```

and my admin.py from my app I have:

```
    from django.contrib import admin

from Clientes.models import Client
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Client)
```

I really don't know what's wrong.

Comment: check whether your **Clientes** app is inside ***INSTALLED_APPS***

Comment: @AnkitTiwari yes, it is. Here´s how it looks: 'Clientes.apps.ClientesConfig',

Comment: Looks like you don't have a admin class defined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [model not showing up in django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984987/model-not-showing-up-in-django-admin)

Comment: @monkut I´ve just tried it and it didn´t work

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Sorry, but it doesn´t answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create admin class so,

Try this:

```py
@admin.register(Client)
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['id','customer','customer_name','customer_surname'] # include more fields.
```

Comment: Just tried it and didn´t work

Comment: @MaximilianoRodriguez In urls.py, you haven't closed the `urlpatterns` list.

Comment: @MaximilianoRodriguez can you edit the question with all your installed apps in settings.py and also the middlewares.

Comment: sure, I've just edited it

Comment: @MaximilianoRodriguez what about urlpatterns list, refer above comment.

Comment: @MaximilianoRodriguez Everything is perfect in Middlewares and Installed apps, at last can you please share apps.py? And please check urlpatterns list, you haven't closed it.

Comment: i've closed urlpattern list(still doesn´t work) and i´ve shared now the apps.py

Comment: @MaximilianoRodriguez Everything seems perfect in all the above files, I think the issue can be with server, PC, so I'd recommend you some things, run server in another port like `python manage.py runserver 5000` and hard refresh through `ctrl+f5` and if then also it does not work, so kindly restart the pc.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much. The answer was actually the runserver 5000

Answer (score 0):

Delete your existing migrations within `<client_folder_name>/migrations/` except `__init__.py` then `python manage.py makemigrations` then `python manage.py migrate` and check again in admin panel.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. How can i delete the existing migrations except init.py? (the command in vsc code)

Comment: You simply have to delete them just like normal files, In your file explorer tab in VS Code select your app in which Clientes model is written, you will see migrations folder in it, delete all files in there except ___init___.py file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).